# How do you get current local DateTime in c# without using system time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the actual current local DateTime (at the client) even if the user has changed the system DateTime to something else.

I have used this:

```
DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

but it looks at the system time, so if the user changes the system DateTime, I wont be able to get the actual DateTime.

I have also thought about getting utc time and converting it but that also looks at system time to calculate the UTC time.

If this cannot be done, is there a way to get the DateTime of the webserver?

The reason for this is to record when certain records are updated/created, and I am trying to avoid a situation where a user can manipulate this time by changing their system time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the type of application?

Comment: FWIW, servers are often configured to update their clocks from a network time source periodically. Is a leap second going to be a problem? And what Joel said in his answer.

Answer (score 8):

Since it's a **WEB APPLICATION**, all the **back end code will be hosted in your server,** that means you have **full control** with the timezone there.

You don't need to and should not care about the timezone passed from the client side because you can never assume it will be reliable.

Another thing is, if you're not careful, your web server's timezone might be different with the timezone used by your database server (I've faced it before). So here comes the best practice

**BEST PRACTICE**: Use UTC timezone everywhere and convert to local timezone where needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the time at the client, you don't use C# at all. The code you have can only ever possibly run on the web server. No C# code in ASP.Net MVC ever runs on the client computer.

To get the time at the client, you have to get it from either javascript or a 3rd party plug-in. In either case, you're still likely dependant on data submitted via the HTTP protocol, which is *easy* manipulate outside of the browser. If the client really wants to lie to you, there's **nothing** you can do about it.